# Inspiration for a unique hybrid character in 4E?

Tags: dnd-4e, character-creation, optimization

I have been using Wizards' character creator, but I can't come up with anything unique.  I would very much like to use a hybrid, but I've had trouble making one that would work at early levels (we are starting at 1).  I know there are many ways to have unconventional characters (such as a ranged healer) and I'm open to those ideas as well.

*I don't want to be, just another striker, or just another tank.*

I do enjoy all classes, but enjoy tanks and healers that lean towards strikers the best.

How can I make a hybrid character which is unique but not useless at low levels?

Edit: Sorry, I'm new to the site, I very much appreciate your kindness and understanding.  I re-worded the question as I think it will whittle the answers down.

Comment: Hi Russell, Stackexchange sites don't allow discussions, but instead ask poster ask **answerable** questions. Please check out the [faq](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/faq)

Comment: I've just edited your question to make it more readable and answerable (potentially) let us know what you want, edit it or comment otherwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you might benefit from this [blog post](http://greywulf.net/2011/05/interesting-characters-and-the-sliding-scale/)

### Interesting characters and the sliding scale

> One thing that all of these choices brings is the idea of a sliding scale. With 4e D&D, you can choose how much of the character concept affects the build, which in turn reflects the importance the PC places on the things which shape him (or her).

It all depends on what you want to play, you say you like all classes and roles. But what sources of power? Do you have a specific *concept*?

If you like Defenders (effectively tanks) that can strike then check out this: [What striker builds let you play a secondary defender role?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/1857/what-striker-builds-let-you-play-a-secondary-defender-role)

If you want to mix Striker and Controller, check out this: [What class/builds can be used to fulfill both striker and controller roles?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/5801/what-class-builds-can-be-used-to-fulfill-both-striker-and-controller-roles)

And for general Hybrid advice, check out [this section](http://community.wizards.com/wiki/Dnd:CharOp/Hybrids) on the charop section of the D&D boards.

Ultimately how you mix two character to create a unique character is down to you, your concept, and your in-game choices. *Not just mechanics*. To help with backgrounds, check out options like Backgrounds, Themes and [Multi-classing](http://community.wizards.com/go/thread/view/75882/19647686/MC_dips__what_to_MC_into_if_youve_got_nothing_better_to_do?sdb=1&post_num=1#334432502). That way a good character lies. People even write [papers](http://www.mendeley.com/research/constrained-optimization-dungeons-dragons-theory-requirements-generation-effective-character-creation/) on this stuff!

Comment: very cool thanks, i'm going to actually wright some scales up for visuals, i liked their idea of hybrid+multiclassing and even half-elf if you want.  i'm thinking maybe a revenant so you can have really cool back stories/explanations

Comment: No worries @Russell . Do you know how *upvoting* and *downvoting* works on this site?

Comment: I'm not sure how they work.  I figured the function would be to show which questions or comments are "better."  My problem is, it appears i don't have enough reputation, as this is my first post on this site.

Comment: Ah I remember now. This isn't the ideal question to pose here, so I don't know whe you'll get reputation from an upvote. It needs a closed objective answer, not a subjective (based on opinion) answer. See [here](http://www.differencebetween.net/language/difference-between-objective-and-subjective/)

Comment: I understand much better now, this community is great, I'll be here again for sure!

Answer (score 2):

One hybrid character i had given a shot to create (never played him) that was of an interesting concept to me was a fighter/runepriest. Their basic stats can be similar, Strength and Constitution if i recall correctly, and by the Hybrid Talent feat you can lean towards heal/support, tank or striker.

As of the playstyle, i found it really interesting to have some one that at first looks like a common fighter, but when in need, evokes seals and glyphs of destruction/creation to aid him.

He could be a keeper of the sacred sigils of a god, or if your DM is lenient enough, become the keeper of the marks of the far realm, the invoker of powers from beyond this word, the disciple of things that should not be named, and similar Cthulhu mythos referances that i will avoid by stopping here.

Comment: i'll try it out later,  the secret life part is a pretty cool idea, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'll be frank. If you want to have a really unique character focus on your back story and personality. There are only so many options available to characters in 4e. Sure you can come up with a great character design that no one else has created. But then you have to ask yourself the following questions

- Does the character work (for whatever work means)?
- Does the character fit in/fill a need in my party?
- Can I play this character effectively?

If the answer to any of these questions is no then you need to re-evaluate your character creation strategies. Go for a simpler character and spend more time thinking about the character's story.

As much fun as it is to come up with a mechanically "unique" character, I personally thing its much more compelling to have a mechanically useful character with an interesting personality and back story to go with it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I play with newer players, so me accommodating my team happens often.  I myself haven't been playing for too long, which puts me in an awkward position.  We try to work on stories as much as we can with our characters too.

Comment: @Russell I'd suggest the simplest character designs possible then. Look at the essentials characters. They provide nice mechanically simple characters that you can then flavor and write story around. Complexity is better served in story than mechanics most of the time. (and I'm a mathy mechanics nerd)

Answer (score 1):

A character that I've made and hope to use one day is a Archer Warlord.  This isn't a hybrid strictly speaking, but it is a ranged leader, and can add some nice offense bonuses/extra attacks for the party.

Unfortunately with the pure hybrid system, very few character combinations seem be effective, since you need their primary stats and weapon usage to be the same.